# Error installing iconv on Ubuntu 11.10, using RVM

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu, rvm

I installed RVM, installed the suggested dependencies, but whenever I try to install iconv I get this error:

```
lpicado@lpicado-HP-EliteBook-8530w:~/app$ rvm pkg install iconv
Fetching libiconv-1.13.1.tar.gz to /home/lpicado/.rvm/archives
Extracting libiconv-1.13.1.tar.gz to /home/lpicado/.rvm/src
Prepare libiconv in /home/lpicado/.rvm/src/libiconv-1.13.1.
Error running 'autoreconf -is --force', please read /home/lpicado/.rvm/log/libiconv/autoreconf.log
Configuring libiconv in /home/lpicado/.rvm/src/libiconv-1.13.1.
Compiling libiconv in /home/lpicado/.rvm/src/libiconv-1.13.1.
Error running 'make ', please read /home/lpicado/.rvm/log/libiconv/make.log
```

The `autoreconf.log` file says:

```
[2012-01-29 01:14:44] autoreconf -is --force
configure.ac:100: warning: macro `AM_ICONV' not found in library
configure.ac:101: warning: macro `AM_GNU_GETTEXT' not found in library
configure.ac:149: warning: macro `AM_LANGINFO_CODESET' not found in library
configure.ac:134: warning: AC_LANG_CONFTEST: no AC_LANG_SOURCE call detected in body
../../lib/autoconf/lang.m4:194: AC_LANG_CONFTEST is expanded from...
../../lib/autoconf/general.m4:2591: _AC_COMPILE_IFELSE is expanded from...
../../lib/autoconf/general.m4:2607: AC_COMPILE_IFELSE is expanded from...
../../lib/m4sugar/m4sh.m4:606: AS_IF is expanded from...
../../lib/autoconf/general.m4:2032: AC_CACHE_VAL is expanded from...
../../lib/autoconf/general.m4:2053: AC_CACHE_CHECK is expanded from...
configure.ac:134: the top level
configure.ac:134: warning: AC_LANG_CONFTEST: no AC_LANG_SOURCE call detected in body
../../lib/autoconf/lang.m4:194: AC_LANG_CONFTEST is expanded from...
../../lib/autoconf/general.m4:2591: _AC_COMPILE_IFELSE is expanded from...
../../lib/autoconf/general.m4:2607: AC_COMPILE_IFELSE is expanded from...
../../lib/m4sugar/m4sh.m4:606: AS_IF is expanded from...
../../lib/autoconf/general.m4:2032: AC_CACHE_VAL is expanded from...
../../lib/autoconf/general.m4:2053: AC_CACHE_CHECK is expanded from...
configure.ac:134: the top level
configure.ac:63: warning: macro `AM_LANGINFO_CODESET' not found in library
libtoolize: putting auxiliary files in AC_CONFIG_AUX_DIR, `build-aux'.
libtoolize: linking file `build-aux/config.guess'
libtoolize: linking file `build-aux/config.sub'
libtoolize: linking file `build-aux/install-sh'
libtoolize: linking file `build-aux/ltmain.sh'
libtoolize: Consider adding `AC_CONFIG_MACRO_DIR([m4])' to configure.ac and
libtoolize: rerunning libtoolize, to keep the correct libtool macros in-tree.
libtoolize: Consider adding `-I m4' to ACLOCAL_AMFLAGS in Makefile.am.
configure.ac:63: warning: macro `AM_LANGINFO_CODESET' not found in library
configure.ac:63: error: possibly undefined macro: AM_LANGINFO_CODESET
  If this token and others are legitimate, please use m4_pattern_allow.
  See the Autoconf documentation.
autoreconf: /usr/bin/autoconf failed with exit status: 1
```

The `make.log` file says:

```
[2012-01-29 01:14:44] autoreconf -is --force
configure.ac:100: warning: macro `AM_ICONV' not found in library
configure.ac:101: warning: macro `AM_GNU_GETTEXT' not found in library
configure.ac:149: warning: macro `AM_LANGINFO_CODESET' not found in library
configure.ac:134: warning: AC_LANG_CONFTEST: no AC_LANG_SOURCE call detected in body
../../lib/autoconf/lang.m4:194: AC_LANG_CONFTEST is expanded from...
../../lib/autoconf/general.m4:2591: _AC_COMPILE_IFELSE is expanded from...
../../lib/autoconf/general.m4:2607: AC_COMPILE_IFELSE is expanded from...
../../lib/m4sugar/m4sh.m4:606: AS_IF is expanded from...
../../lib/autoconf/general.m4:2032: AC_CACHE_VAL is expanded from...
../../lib/autoconf/general.m4:2053: AC_CACHE_CHECK is expanded from...
configure.ac:134: the top level
configure.ac:134: warning: AC_LANG_CONFTEST: no AC_LANG_SOURCE call detected in body
../../lib/autoconf/lang.m4:194: AC_LANG_CONFTEST is expanded from...
../../lib/autoconf/general.m4:2591: _AC_COMPILE_IFELSE is expanded from...
../../lib/autoconf/general.m4:2607: AC_COMPILE_IFELSE is expanded from...
../../lib/m4sugar/m4sh.m4:606: AS_IF is expanded from...
../../lib/autoconf/general.m4:2032: AC_CACHE_VAL is expanded from...
../../lib/autoconf/general.m4:2053: AC_CACHE_CHECK is expanded from...
configure.ac:134: the top level
configure.ac:63: warning: macro `AM_LANGINFO_CODESET' not found in library
libtoolize: putting auxiliary files in AC_CONFIG_AUX_DIR, `build-aux'.
libtoolize: linking file `build-aux/config.guess'
libtoolize: linking file `build-aux/config.sub'
libtoolize: linking file `build-aux/install-sh'
libtoolize: linking file `build-aux/ltmain.sh'
libtoolize: Consider adding `AC_CONFIG_MACRO_DIR([m4])' to configure.ac and
libtoolize: rerunning libtoolize, to keep the correct libtool macros in-tree.
libtoolize: Consider adding `-I m4' to ACLOCAL_AMFLAGS in Makefile.am.
configure.ac:63: warning: macro `AM_LANGINFO_CODESET' not found in library
configure.ac:63: error: possibly undefined macro: AM_LANGINFO_CODESET
  If this token and others are legitimate, please use m4_pattern_allow.
  See the Autoconf documentation.
autoreconf: /usr/bin/autoconf failed with exit status: 1
```

My Ruby version is:

```
lpicado@lpicado-HP-EliteBook-8530w:~/app$ ruby -v
ruby 1.8.7 (2011-06-30 patchlevel 352) [x86_64-linux]
```

Rails:

```
lpicado@lpicado-HP-EliteBook-8530w:~/app$ rails -v
Rails 3.2.1
```

Rubygems:

```
lpicado@lpicado-HP-EliteBook-8530w:~/app$ gem -v
1.7.2
```

I tried using [`rvm pkg install iconv`](http://beginrescueend.com/packages/iconv/) but it didn't make a difference.

Answer (score 1):

First try installing these packages and then install iconv using RVM once again:

```
sudo apt-get install  \ 
   aspell aspell-en autoconf automake bc ccache colordiff  \ 
   coreutils cvs doxygen flex g++ gettext git-core gnuplot  \ 
   graphviz help2man imagemagick libboost-all-dev  \ 
   liblinphone-dev libx11-dev make pkg-config  \ 
   python-docutils python-yaml python2.6 socat  \ 
   sun-java6-jdk swig tex4ht texinfo texlive-base  \ 
   texlive-binaries texlive-latex-extra transfig valgrind
```

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to install iconv via rvm, ubuntu provide proper versions of packages:

```
rm -rf $rvm_path/usr

rvm requirements # and follow the instructions

rvm reinstall 1.8.7
```

You need to reinstall all the installed rubies

Comment: By rubies you mean gems? I tried iconv --v and it seems the package was there, should I be good to go?

Comment: rubies from `rvm list`, but also any gems with native extensions might be affected